# Connect Python Backend on Windows with Ikea Tradfri

Tags: python, linux, windows

I'm trying to connect my python Backend with Ikeas's Tradfri to control it from my own app.
I found that for this communication I need `DTLSSocket` and `libcoap`, but according to this repo here (https://github.com/ggravlingen/pytradfri/issues/97) there are some major problems installing these libs on windows.

I tried it myself and it's still not working. Installing `DTLSSocket` on Windows results in:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for DTLSSocket
```

Of course I could use a VM or the WSL service to build a linux environment, but that's actually not what I want.

Is anyone of you aware of another solution how to connect to the tradfri gateway or knows how to install the required libs on Windows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
pip install conda
```

Then try again.